# Хранение данных объектов в C#, что выбрать?

Tags: c#

Я только начал изучать C# как хобби для несерьёзного программирования. Первое задание - простая консольная RPG-подобная игра. Герой ходит по пещерам, сражается с монстрами и собирает сундуки.

В ходе игры надо генерировать предметы (оружие и доспехи), изменять их данные (показатель прочности), работать с инвентарем. Я уже смог описать нужные классы и конструкторы и могу создавать новые предметы со случайными параметрами. Но экземпляров этих классов будет много, после каждого боя выпадает новый предмет.

Где хранить данные об этих предметах, чтобы было проще видеть происходящее и не слишком сложно в реализации? В списках List? В xml-файле? В excel-таблице? В базе данных? Еще где-то?

UPDATE: Речь не о реализации сохранения/загрузки, а о хранении данных в процессе игры. Например, если складывать всё в коллекцию, то не очень понятно как смотреть и проверять, корректно ли применяются изменения. Возможно, для этого хорошо подойдет SQLite?

Comment: Ну вы тут не описали как и где эти предметы хранятся в процессе самой игры. Например, если предметы падают на землю, то это можно уже описать как WorldObject и для хранения будет иной контейнер. Например класс World, в котором будут описаны в картах все объекты с уникальным ID. Если вещи выпадают виртуально, то вам уже нужно смотреть в сторону Inventory класса с картами предметов. Карты или списки - это решать вам. Если предметы будут иметь одинаковые свойства и не стопковые, то без уникального идентификатора не обойтись,

Comment: Если в процессе игры, то лучше обойтись без файлов и БД, если конечно это не ММОРПГ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о хобби, то для начала сойдет и обычная коллекция.

А вообще очень рекомендую изучить игровые паттерны проектирования, большинство ответов Вы найдете здесь:

1. [Оригинал на английском](https://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/)
2. [Русский перевод](https://martalex.gitbooks.io/gameprogrammingpatterns/)

Очень поможет в изучении подходов к построению понятной игровой архитектуры, которая позволит легко создавать новые объекты с динамическими параметрами.

Если объектов действительно много, то для оптимизации производительности и памяти предлагаю вот этот паттерн из шаблонов оптимизации:
[Пул Объектов](https://martalex.gitbooks.io/gameprogrammingpatterns/chapter-6/6.3-object-pool.html)

Comment: Обычная коллекция помогла решить проблему. В моём случает List<T>. Я научился складывать в неё объекты, выводить их, определять индекс и по индексу редактировать значения полей.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже была проблема с хранением обьектов и я решил её так: в процессе работы программы она создавала обьекты и сохраняла их в коллекции (в данном случае List), далее при нажатии кнопки коллекция подвергалась сериализации и сохранялась в файлике формата json. когда нужно было загрузить данные файлик десериализировался опять в коллекцию List с теми же обьектами. В общем тебе может помочь сериализация и десериализация в json.